# Javascript code block finishes BEFORE it gets back the result of a called function? What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call, ascx

As the title says, I have a block of Javascript code in a .JS file. Here I call a function in a seperate ASCX file which changes the x variable.

```
$('#button').bind('click', function (event) {
Function();

if(x == true){do something}
if(x == false){do something else}
});
```

In the ASCX file I have the variable and the function:

```
var x;
function Function(){
if(y > 100)
x = true
if(y < 100)
x = false
}
```

I would expect that, if the button is clicked, the function would execute (which it does), the variable would change depending on the conditions (which also happens). However, the code uses the value of x of how it was BEFORE the code ran.

So if x was true before the button was clicked, and one would click the button, the outcome would always evaluate as true even if the conditions of y should actually have x evaluate as false.

I am not sure why this is happening. Merging the files so that both the function and the call are in the same location is unfortunately not an option. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, Rob

Comment: As Ray says, what's your y value? Without an y value your x never gets updated. You mention it's two seperate files, do both files have access to both x and y? Also, please don't call your functions 'Function', you risk overwriting things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return it from `Function`.
You can check further using returned value.

You dont need to assign and check for update in calling context.

One JS file :

```
$('#button').bind('click', function(event) {
    x = Function();

    if(x == true) { //do something }

    if(x == false) { 
        //do something else
      }
});
```

Second JS file :

```
function Function() {
    if (y > 100)
        return true
    if (y < 100)
        return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').bind('click', function (event) {
   x= Function();

    if(x == true){/*do something*/}
    if(x == false){/*do something else*/}
});

var x;
var y = 10;

function Function(){
    if(y > 100)
        x = true
    if(y < 100)
        x = false
}
```

Comment: And what did you change?

Comment: there si no value for y?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!